# What design pattern to use? Connectivity and the UI model

Tags: design-patterns

Depending on the type of the object (model), it is necessary to open the desired window. The model should not have knowledge of the user interface. What patterns solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right forum for this question and the question should be expanded upon, too.  Maybe you're looking for  MVC, MVP, or MVVM?

Comment: No. These design patterns are not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) 'could' be what you are looking for.

The 'Model' class(es)  have the following method:

```
public class MyClassA {

    ...

    public void accept(Visitor v) { 
        v.visit(this); 
   } 
}
public class MyClassB {

    ...

    public void accept(Visitor v) { 
        v.visit(this); 
   } 
}
public class MyClassC {

    ...

    public void accept(Visitor v) { 
        v.visit(this); 
   } 
}
public class MyClassD {

    ...

    public void accept(Visitor v) { 
        v.visit(this); 
   } 
}
```

The 'Visitor' then has a series of methods named:

```
public void visit(MyClassA instance){...}
public void visit(MyClassB instance){...}
public void visit(MyClassC instance){...}
public void visit(MyClassD instance){...}
```

This makes use of polymorphism and the ability to dynamically dispatch the appropriate method based on what the input class is.

This allows your Model Class(es) to be unaware of what algorithm is 'processing' it (visiting it), but with all design patterns this creates a coupling between the visitor class and the classes that it can support 'visiting'. So there is a trade off here of allowing the Model to be simpler/not knowing what it is connecting to.